# Replace values in certain section in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file which have several sections, I have to change the values of all parameters in section `[Test2]`.

Input:

```
[Test_1]
abc=123
def=456
.
.
.
so on

[Test_2]
abc=123
def=456
.
.
.
so on

[Test_3]
abc=123
def=456
.
.
.
so on
```

Expected output:

```
[Test_1]
abc=123
def=456
.
.
.
so on

[Test_2]
abc=111
def=222
.
.
.
so on

[Test_3]
abc=123
def=456
.
.
.
so on
```

I tried this:

```
sed "/\[Test_2\]/{n;s/^\(abc=\).*/\1$val1/';}" input > output.new && mv output.new input
sed "/\[Test_2\]/{n;s/^\(def=\).*/\1$val2/';}" input > output.new && mv output.new input
```

Where `$val1=111` and `$val2=222`.

But I am not getting expected output. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to use Ansible. 
Your file is an ini_file file format and Ansible manage this kind of file very well.

Check http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ini_file_module.html

The syntax is very simple, in your example :

```
- ini_file: dest=/anotherconf
            section=Test_2
            option=abc
            value=111
```

Comment: I put this `- ini_file: dest=/path-to-file section=Test_2 option=abc value=111` inside one function in bash script. But it said  `- ini_file: command not found`. I am on SunOS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me --

```
sed  '/Test_2/ {n;s/^\(abc=\).*$/\1'"$val1"'/;x;n;s/^\(def=\).*$/\1'"$val2"'/;H;g}'
```